# WPF - application branding solution

Tags: c#, wpf, build, windows-installer, branding

I'm new on a 4-years-somehow-complicated `WPF` project, with basic knowledge of `WPF` technology and coming from web-based products.

The product always released for two clients, with different branding, below are some of the differences:

```
1. Images in the resources folder.
2. Change (name, target, icon) in the installer project.
3. Installer general properties > change {AddRemoveProgramsIcon , Product Name , Title}/
4. Installer UpgradeCode.
5. Update msi installer name.
6. Remove dlls from references.
7. Config. files: CommonAssemblyInfo.cs> change AssemblyTitle, AssemblyProduct
8. Search and replace in many String resources files.
```

So, is there a feasible way to make all - or most - of these manual steps to be done automatically? I've found some articles about Pre and Post build actions but never try that before, if it would be the suitable solution, how many points would be covered?

Thank You.

Comment: The fact that you're suggesting pre and post build actions makes me think that maybe you should leave that WPF job... and maybe programming altogether. Really, you just need logic to achieve these goals... you could even follow the State pattern to display a different view for the different users. Also, this question has nothing to do with WPF, so you might think about removing the WPF tag.

Comment: @Sheridan I can't find your HELP still .. thanks for your input :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what 'help' you're expecting from posting this question. Nobody is going to provide you with a full working solution and there aren't any built into .NET. As I said, *you just need logic to achieve these goals*... one by one... and good luck.

Comment: The funny thing is I gave him that help and he never even bothered to upvote or accept my answer.  I have spent 4 years of my career in a "product line development" environment dealing with these vary isues for a $100 million/year company.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an exercise in discrete math/set theory.  In a Windows Installer world you can create Merge Modules to encapsulate a collection of components.  In the most simplistic example you would need three merge modules:

1) Client A Files Merge Module

2) Client B Files Merge Module

3) Common Files Merge Module

Common files can further be split up if there are multiple optional features to install.  You can also split up Client A files and Client B files if they contain unique configuration data for these optional features.

It's best to also create unique EXE names (ClientA.exe and ClientB.exe ) with their own branding and icons so that when you consume them into their respective merge modules you can give them unique shortcut information.   Make these EXE very thin veneers with core functionality in a common DLL (DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself)

Finally you create 2 MSI projects that are also very thin veneers.  The just contain the ProductName, UpgradeCode, Feature Treee and Dialog UI's.  No files as all the files are not referenced via merge modules.

If you are using a tool such as Windows Installer XML or InstallShield to generate your UI there is a way of building both MSI's out of a single project that way nothing is repeated.  This gets into very advanced authoring though and requires a firm understanding of "basic" MSI authoring before delving into advanced abstractions.   Also WiX supports "Fragments" and InstallShield supports "Developer Installation Manifests"  but speaking strictly Windows Installer only Merge Modules is supported across all tools.